# Is there any alternate solution of IN Clause for more than 1000 values

Tags: oracle

I want to use more than 1000 value with IN Clause that is not supported by this clause. eg.

select prodCode from Products where prodId IN (1,2,3.....,1020);

Can someone suggest me for any alternate solution??

Comment: in the duplicate suggestion you'll find various workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Where did the values for `prodId` that you are putting into your IN clause originate from?

If they originated from another query, then you should combine the two queries.

If they originated from some complicated process or an external data source, then you should store them in a temporary table.  The temporary table can just contain a `prodId` column.  Join to that table instead of using an IN list.

Comment: yes prodId I am getting from different query of different table.

Comment: @PriyaPrajapati In that case, replace the list in brackets with a SELECT that returns the list from the other table.  Or re-write as a join to that table.